# how to count SUM YTD format

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table payments(Actual there is about 100k records, different categories, clients etc):

```
Client      Dt          Amt  Category
  1       201312        10       Tax
  1       201401        10       Tax
  1       201405        10       Tax
  1       201406        10       Tax
  2       201311        10       Tax
```

And i want to make cumulative sum YTD for category tax for every client. So the result will be like this:

```
Client      Dt          Amt  Category
  1       201312        10       Tax
  1       201401        10       Tax
  1       201405        20       Tax
  1       201406        30       Tax
  2       201311        10       Tax
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.Client, a.Dt, SUM(b.Amt) AS Amt, a.Category
FROM payments a
JOIN payments b ON b.Client = a.Client
 AND b.Category = a.Category
 AND b.Dt <= a.Dt
 AND YEAR(b.Dt) = YEAR(a.Dt)
WHERE a.Category = 'Tax'
GROUP BY a.Client, a.Dt, a.Category
```